# Set sum of graphs of linear maps is a graph only if the maps are same

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces, proof-writing, linear-transformations

Let $S, T \in \text{Hom}(V, W)$. How do you show that the set sum of the graphs of these two maps is itself a graph of a function $f:V \rightarrow W$ only if $S=T$?

I’ve managed to show that $T \in \text{Hom}(V, W)$ iff its graph is a subspace of the Cartesian product $V \times W$. So the set sum of the graphs of $T$ and $S$ is also a subspace of the Cartesian product. Does this help with the proof?

Comment: @Lukas Thanks for your reply. How does $U + W$ is a subspace of $V$ for $U,W \subset V$ imply that $U \subset W \vee W \subset U$?  This is the proof for the fact the set sum of any two subspaces is a subspace: https://yutsumura.com/the-sum-of-subspaces-is-a-subspace-of-a-vector-space/ ; So if there existed two subspaces s.t. one is not a subset of the other, by applying this theorem we can see that the claim you made is false. So essentially, you are assuming that there are no pair of subspaces such that one is not a subset of the other

Comment: @Lukas In the second part of your argument, you said that  one of the graphs being a subset of the other one implies that the graphs are the same. Two sets are the same iff both are subsets of each other. You only said that one is a subset of the other so I’m not sure how the conclusion follows

Comment: Oh, I'm very sorry. I made a big mistake. Consider everything I wrote false. I talked about the union of two subspaces because I didn't read your question properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From page 49:

> **3.6** Let $S$ and $T$ be nonzero linear maps from $V$ to $W.$ The definition of the map $S + T$ is *not* the same as the set sum of (the graphs of) $S$ and $T$ as subspaces of $V \times W.$ Show that the set sum of (the graphs of) $S$ and $T$ *cannot be* a graph unless $S = T.$

I can't find the definition in the book, but I presume the **set sum** of $S$ and $T$ is $\{s + t : s \in S \text{ and } t \in T\}.$

The map $S,$ when identified with its graph, is the set $\{(v, Sv) : v \in V\}$ ; similarly, $T$ is identified with the subset $\{(v, Tv) : v \in V\}$ of $V \times W.$

So, the set sum of $S$ and $T$ is the set
$$
\{(v, Sv) + (v', Tv') : v \in V \text{ and } v' \in V\} =
\{(v + v', Sv + Tv') : v \in V \text{ and } v' \in V\}.
$$
In order for this to be the graph of a function, the set
$$
\{Sv + Tv' : v \in V \text{ and } v' \in V \text{ and } v + v' = v''\}
$$
must be a singleton, for every vector $v'' \in V.$ In particular, this must be so when $v'' = 0.$ Therefore, the value of the expression $Sv + T(-v) = Sv - Tv$ is constant for all $v \in V.$ Because its value for $v = 0$ is $0,$ we have $Sv - Tv = 0$ for all $v \in V,$ i.e., $Sv - Tv$ for all $v \in V,$ i.e., $S = T.$

If I'm not mistaken, the hypothesis that $S$ and $T$ are nonzero is not needed.

Comment: The reference (which will disappear when the bounty period has ended) is to Lynn H. Loomis and Shlomo Sternberg, *Advanced Calculus* (Addison-Wesley 1968; revised edition Jones and Bartlett 1990).